# MySQL SQL statement with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have the following SQL statement

```
SELECT be.*, it.order_number
FROM songs AS be

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT song_id, order_number
    FROM items
    WHERE order_status = 1
) it
ON be.id = it.song_id

INNER JOIN orders AS or
ON it.order_number = or.order_number

WHERE be.active = 0
```

I can't seem to understand why this statement does not produce any results. When I remove the following line;

```
INNER JOIN orders AS or
ON it.order_number = or.order_number
```

It seems to produce results, and I know that the `order_number` does exist in the `orders` table - so it's clearly incorrect syntax but i'm not sure where to go from here? Appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that "or" might be a reserved word?

Comment: Not until you just said it, thanks Ian, silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this particular instance is that the `or` in the query is a reserved word.  You can use that if you wish, but you'll have to quote it, like so

```
SELECT be.*, it.order_number
FROM songs AS be

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT song_id, order_number
    FROM items
    WHERE order_status = 1
) it
ON be.id = it.song_id

INNER JOIN orders AS "or"
ON it.order_number = "or".order_number

WHERE be.active = 0
```

Generally though, for readability, I'd avoid such names.  If you have to quote it or escape it, it's probably a bad name.